# Is there any pop up dialog control in Orbeon form builder

Tags: orbeon

Is there any pop up dialog for select data for a text box in Orbeon Form builder. Which will allow user to search item and select for a text box on Form runner.

Comment: Hi Apel, did one of the solutions/workarounds suggested in my answer below work for you? And of course you'll just let me know if you still have any concern related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no control that uses a pop-up dialog for the search. However:

- In some cases the autocomplete can be used for that purpose, if the amount of information the autocomplete shows is enough to allow users to make a choice. Once an item has been selected, you can show more information related to the selection that was made in other controls.
- Once RFE [#3803](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3803) is implemented, which is planned for 2018.2, you'll be able to use any field (or a combination thereof) for the search, and a repeated grid to show results.
- Finally, you could implement your own component that uses a pop-up, and plug into Form Builder. But of course, depending on the situation, it is possible that this could call for a larger investment in time than acceptable.